# Three react fiber OrbitControls ref object throws error in typescript at build phase (code does work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-ref, react-three-drei

I am currently stuck on a typescript error regarding the type of a ref object (as far as I know). I am quite new to typescript so i don't understand how to resolve the issue!

I have appended the tootip typescript gave me, and the error it throws upon build stage.
Furthermore, I use the react-three-drei and react-three-fiber libraries for compositing the three.js object

**This is the error thrown:**

```
src/components/models/web/Plane.tsx:120:22 - error TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject<OrbitControlsProps | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<OrbitControls> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<OrbitControlsProps | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<OrbitControls>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'OrbitControlsProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'OrbitControls | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'OrbitControls | null'.

120       <OrbitControls ref={cameraRef} />
                         ~~~

  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:134:9
    134         ref?: Ref<T> | undefined;
                ~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OrbitControlsProps & RefAttributes<OrbitControls>'
```

**And this is my code:**

```
import {
  MeshDistortMaterial,
  MeshWobbleMaterial,
  OrbitControls,
  OrbitControlsProps,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  PointMaterial,
  Text,
} from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import React, { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../theme/theme";
export default function Box() {
  const cameraRef = useRef<OrbitControlsProps>();
  useFrame(() => {
    var angle = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    cameraRef.current?.setPolarAngle(1.1 + angle / 10);
  });
  console.log(cameraRef);
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <>
      <PerspectiveCamera
        makeDefault ...
      [truncated]
      />

      <OrbitControls ref={cameraRef} />
      <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]} rotation={[-1.5, 0, 0]}>
        <planeBufferGeometry args={[25, 10, 50, 50]} />
        <meshLambertMaterial
          attach="material"
          wireframe
          distort={0}
          color={theme.secondary}
        />
      </mesh>

      <fog
        attach="fog"
        color={theme.primary}
        near={1}
        far={3.5}
        position={[0, 0, 0]}
      />
      <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]}>
        <pointLight color={theme.cta} intensity={4} position={[0, 1, 0]} />
      </mesh>
    </>
  );
}
```

**This is the tooltip that I get from intellisense:**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/730,
the solution is:

```
import type { OrbitControls as OrbitControlsImpl } from 'three-stdlib'

const ref = useRef<OrbitControlsImpl>(null)

<OrbitControls ref={ref} />
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! This does indeed work

Comment: man.. how should one know this? how? I mean.. how?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the type from `useRef<OrbitControls>` to `useRef<any>` does work, but it isn't the best practice

Comment: As even TS noobs know, this just wiping away types altogether. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the type of `cameraRef` as the type of props of `OrbitControls` (`OrbitControlsProps`), instead of `OrbitControls` itself. Use:

```
type OrbitControlsType = typeof OrbitControls

const cameraRef = useRef<OrbitControlsType>()
```

Comment: That is what i tried as well, however then I got this error on  useRef<OrbitControls>():

type OrbitControls = /*unresolved*/ any
'OrbitControls' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof OrbitControls'?ts(2749)

Comment: Updated answer. Can you try extracting the type of `OrbitControls` as  `OrbitControlsType` and assign it to `cameraRef`?

Comment: I would love to! But I am a dummy in typescript. Could you provide an example of extracting types?

Comment: Already provided the code to do it in the answer :)

Comment: haha sorry didnt notice, however it does not work :(

this is what i get:
(property) React.RefAttributes<OrbitControls>.ref?: React.Ref<OrbitControls> | undefined
Type 'MutableRefObject<ForwardRefExoticComponent<OrbitControlsProps & RefAttributes<OrbitControls>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<OrbitControls> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<ForwardRefExoticComponent<OrbitControlsProps & RefAttributes<OrbitControls>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type

Comment: Pfff okay so update @Rashomon , I have just changed the type of useRef to useRef<any> and it works. It is probably not a good practice though so if there is a better answer let me know :)